# Rescomm Call fails due to: "Media path is lost due to connectivity issues" error

Tags: webrtc, restcomm

I am using RestComm Connect installed on a cloud VPS.

When making a basic test call to verify setup and connectivity (use default RestComm accounts Bob & Alice; in this case Bob called Alice) the callee side reports the following error:

```
Media path is lost due to connectivity issues; call has been hung up
```

and then then call fails after a SIP '480 Temporarily Unavailable' is sent from callee to caller.

The browser console output looks as follows:

```
WebRTComm.js:4925 2017-10-10 17:06:31.370 WebRTCommCall:onRtcPeerConnectionIceChangeEvent(): Media path is lost due to connectivity issues; call has been hung up 

Stack trace: 
    at commonLog (https://api-test.click2callme.pl/olympus/resources/js/mobicents-libs/WebRTComm.js:4884:10)
    at console.error (https://api-test.click2callme.pl/olympus/resources/js/mobicents-libs/WebRTComm.js:4957:4)
    at WebRTCommCall.onRtcPeerConnectionIceChangeEvent (https://api-test.click2callme.pl/olympus/resources/js/mobicents-libs/WebRTComm.js:3871:12)
    at RTCPeerConnection.peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange (https://api-test.click2callme.pl/olympus/resources/js/mobicents-libs/WebRTComm.js:3047:9)
commonLog @ WebRTComm.js:4925
console.error @ WebRTComm.js:4957
WebRTCommCall.onRtcPeerConnectionIceChangeEvent @ WebRTComm.js:3871
peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange @ WebRTComm.js:3047
WebRTComm.js:4925 2017-10-10 17:06:31.399 WebRTCommCall:close(), received media stats 
    [Arguments.<anonymous> (https://api-test.click2callme.pl/olympus/resources/js/mobicents-libs/WebRTComm.js:2354:13)]
WebRTComm.js:4925 2017-10-10 17:06:31.400 WebRTCommCall:hangup() 
    [WebRTCommCall.hangup (https://api-test.click2callme.pl/olympus/resources/js/mobicents-libs/WebRTComm.js:2186:10)]
WebRTComm.js:4925 2017-10-10 17:06:31.401 PrivateJainSipCallConnector:close(): this.sipCallState=INVITED_INITIAL_STATE 
    [PrivateJainSipCallConnector.close (https://api-test.click2callme.pl/olympus/resources/js/mobicents-libs/WebRTComm.js:484:10)]
WebRTComm.js:4925 2017-10-10 17:06:31.402 SIP message sent: SIP/2.0 480 Temporarily Unavailable
Call-ID: 9b591496fb3bc5aac39075c5ea227d8b@213.32.22.60
CSeq: 1 INVITE
From: <sip:bob@77.255.251.128:57765>;tag=80839608_220982c6_57a5b08a_2ccbc3df
To: <sip:alice@178.43.83.112:63131>;tag=1507647967531
Max-Forwards: 70
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 213.32.22.60:5083;branch=z9hG4bK2ccbc3df_57a5b08a_b9a9c4de-4268-4b16-a02b-4f8795cb4c2c;rport
Contact: <sip:alice@SpUEEE9qhnZn.invalid;transport=wss>
Content-Length: 0
```

The excerpt from RestComm's server.log is as follows:

```
17:04:22,641 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] (pool-AffinityJAIN-thread-47) <message
from="178.43.83.112:63131"
to="213.32.22.60:5083"
time="1507647862640"
isSender="false"
transactionId="z9hg4bk2ccbc3df_57a5b08a_b9a9c4de-4268-4b16-a02b-4f8795cb4c2c"
callId="9b591496fb3bc5aac39075c5ea227d8b@213.32.22.60"
firstLine="SIP/2.0 480 Temporarily Unavailable"
>
<![CDATA[SIP/2.0 480 Temporarily Unavailable
Call-ID: 9b591496fb3bc5aac39075c5ea227d8b@213.32.22.60
CSeq: 1 INVITE
From: <sip:bob@77.255.251.128:57765>;tag=80839608_220982c6_57a5b08a_2ccbc3df
To: <sip:alice@178.43.83.112:63131>;tag=1507647967531
Max-Forwards: 70
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 213.32.22.60:5083;branch=z9hG4bK2ccbc3df_57a5b08a_b9a9c4de-4268-4b16-a02b-4f8795cb4c2c;rport
Contact: <sip:alice@178.43.83.112:63131;transport=wss>
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>
```

This looks like some kind of NAT traversal issue related to ICE/STUN.
I am using a custom STUN server and checked that is works using the below command:

```
vps404561:/$ stun 213.32.22.60:3478
STUN client version 0.96
Primary: Open
Return value is 0x000001
```

Any ideas what might be the exact cause of this problem?
I'm also looking for some hints / tips how to further troubleshoot this issue.

Thanks,

Dominik

Comment: Hi domi. Can you share full web console logs from both caller and callee? Error message 'Media path is lost due to connectivity issues' occurs if the media connectivity is lost between the peers during a call and is usually the result of a bad network connection where STUN pings between the peers fail for more than the predefined timeout (I believer around 10 seconds). Also regarding you stun server, have you made sure that the clients are actually using it?